# Understanding SPL & U-Boot Memory Map using bdinfo?

Tags: compiling, gcc, u-boot, linker

We are using beaglebone black based custom board, I want to write some test results into RAM location from SPL, and read that log and send it via `tftpput` to the host PC.

So far I'm able to do `tftpput` from RAM to the host PC. But on the safer side I want to find RAM location which neither SPL nor U-Boot uses.

To find that out I need suggestions regarding SPL and U-Boot's memory map.
Board's info looks as follows:

```
#bdinfo
arch_number = 0x00000E05
boot_params = 0x80000100
DRAM bank   = 0x00000000
-> start    = 0x80000000  ---> RAM Start address
-> size     = 0x10000000  ---> 256 MB
eth0name    = cpsw
ethaddr     = 1c:ba:8c:9d:5f:f0
current eth = cpsw
ip_addr     = 192.168.1.106
baudrate    = 115200 bps
TLB addr    = 0x8FFF0000  ---> AFA i understand its for Linux right ?
relocaddr   = 0x8FFB3000  ---> Does u-boot use this ?
reloc off   = 0x0F7B3000  ---> Does u-boot use this ?
irq_sp      = 0x8FE92F38  ---> Does u-boot use this ?
sp start    = 0x8FE92F28  ---> Does u-boot use this ?
```

`System.map` file show max address as follows:

```
8083c7ac B __bss_end
8083c7ac B __bss_limit
```

`u-boot.map` file shows max address as follows:

```
 .__bss_end     0x8083c7ac        0x0 arch/arm/lib/libarm.o
                0x8083c7ac                __bss_end
```

`u-boot-spl.map` file shows max address as follows:

```
0x80a0299c                . = ALIGN (0x4)
0x80a0299c                __bss_end = .
```

Can someone explain `bdinfo` please?   I want to understand following fields in `bdinfo`, "TLB addr", "relocaddr", "reloc off", "irq_sp" & "sp start".

So should I consider using 0x81000000 as safe address and start using it for my logging?

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for this but am not finding much about it either. There's the command `help bdinfo` which might prove helpful to you but that's about it. I might be inclined to find the source for `bdinfo` and take a peek at it to see if it sheds further light on what's what in the output.

- [top level of repo](https://android.googlesource.com/device/ti/bootloader/uboot/+/master)
- [source for bdinfo](https://android.googlesource.com/device/ti/bootloader/uboot/+/master/common/cmd_bdinfo.c)